# SpringBoot: @HystrixCommand not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

Fallback method specified with `@HystrixCommand` is not invoked when configured with Eureka/Ribbon aware RestTemplate is used.

pom.xml

```
....
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
....
```

`@SpringBootApplication` config

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrix
public class FileUploadServiceApplication {
   ...
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
  ...
}

@Component
@RefreshScope
public class FileUploadServiceImpl implements FileUploadService {
 ....
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackToMessageQ")
    private void notifyComplete(String fileName) {
     this.restTemplate.exchange(
                    "http://DISCOVERY-CLIENT/api/file/process?filename="+fileName, ....)
      ....
    }
    private void fallbackToMessageQ(String fileName, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("notify threw exception, "+t.getMessage());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(uploadCompleteExchangeName, "", fileName.getBytes());
    }
}
```

when executed it ends just after throwing IllegalStateException for unable to access `DISCOVERY-CLIENT` and never going to access the fallback method, let me know if I have to configure anything else.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for DISCOVERY-CLIENT
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:90)
        at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:163)
```

Answer (score 1):

`@HystrixCommand` is used with an AOP pointcut and your method is `private`. Change its visibility to public.

Comment: Made it public, did not work, moved it to another @component to make it work.

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar thanks, your comment solved my problem!

Comment: This is so weird, I had to do the same, moving it to a @ Service made it work. It didn't work in the same class declared as @ RestController...

Comment: this solution not working